# creating a navbar, items using full space (css)

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm not an expert using css, after 1 hour of time spent on this problem I will ask the community.

my html code:

```
 <div class="content2">
    <div class="Menu">
        <a href="/all">All Investments (3)</a>
        <a href="/payouts">Payouts (0)</a>
    </div>
    ...some other code
 </div>
```

my css code:

```
.content2 {padding: 10px 30px; color: #fff}
.Menu {background: #022000; width: 1000px; height: 50px; margin: 20px auto; text-align: center}
.Menu a {float: left; height: 26px; width: 313px; padding: 12px 10px; color: #fff}
.Menu a:hover {background: #277521}
```

I would like the two items in my Menu class full fill the width of the navbar. Currently they don't take the complete width of the navbar.
    [image: picture]

Comment: try giving width:100% to .Menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `width: 50%;` and modify the padding as `padding: 12px 0px;`.

**Explanation:**

- `width: 50%` : As there are 2 elements, this will enable each element to take 50% of the parent's width.
- `padding: 12px 0px` : padding 0px for right and left helps remove the extra space required for each element.

```css
.content2 {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff
}
.Menu {
  background: #022000;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center
}
.Menu a {
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  color: #fff;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.Menu a:hover {
  background: #277521
}
```

```html
<div class="content2">
  <div class="Menu">
    <a href="/all">All Investments (3)</a>
    <a href="/payouts">Payouts (0)</a>
  </div>
  ...some other code
</div>
```

Comment: What when menu has 3 items? or 4? Change the width to corresponding percentage each time?

Comment: It's upto the user to decide. `display:flex` can be a better option in such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with flex. Add these styles:

```
.Menu {display: flex;}
.Menu a {flex: 1;}
```

This will work with any number of menu items, not only 2.

Tip: flex is a very powerful property and I suggest you research it a little if you are interested why my code works.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way.

Give `width:50%` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to `a`. And change `height:50px;`

```css
.content2 {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff
}
.Menu {
  background: #022000;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center
}
.Menu a {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Menu a:hover {
  background: #277521
}
```

```html
<div class="content2">
  <div class="Menu">
    <a href="/all">All Investments (3)</a>
    <a href="/payouts">Payouts (0)</a>
  </div>
  ...some other code
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayddq0j1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content2 {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  color: #fff
}
.Menu {
  background: #022000;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center
}
.Menu a {
  float: left;
  height: 26px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  color: #fff;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.Menu a:hover {
  background: #277521
}
```

```html
<div class="content2">
  <div class="Menu">
    <a href="/all">All Investments (3)</a>
    <a href="/payouts">Payouts (0)</a>
  </div>
  ...some other code
</div>
```